# Uso da variável local não atribuída de duas strings em código de C#

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Meu código deve ser inserido o gênero da pessoa, altura e idade de uma pessoa em um laço de repetição para 10 pessoas.

O código deve mostrar o **maior peso, menor peso, médias das alturas das 10 pessoas, a quantidade de homens e o gênero da pessoa mais pesada**.

Mas está ocorrendo um erro de uso da variável local não atribuída das `Strings` `sexo, pessoamaispesada` e queria saber concertar isso

A seguir as linhas do meu código que aparecem as variáveis `sexo, pessoamaispesada`

```
// Declarando as strings
string sexo, pessoamaispesada;
```

---

```
// Parte que pergunta o gênero da pessoa
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Digite o sexo da pessoa {i} (M - masculino | F - feminino): ");
    sexo = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

```
/// Capturar a pessoa de determinado genero com maior peso
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (peso > maiorpeso)
    {
        maiorpeso = peso;
        sexo = pessoamaispesada; // Uso da variável local não atribuída "pessoamaispesada"
    }
}
```

---

```
//  Contabiliza a quantidade de homens
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (sexo == "M" || sexo == "m") // Uso da variável local não atribuída "sexo"
    {
        qnthomens++;
    }
}

// Imprimindo a pessoa mais pesada de determinado gênero 
Console.Write($"A pessoa mais pesada é {pessoamaispesada}");
```

Comment: Ficou meio confuso o entendimento.
Você pode postar o código completo? Assim dá pra visualizar melhor o problema.

Comment: Seu código poderia ser postado na sua totalidade?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic já postei.

Comment: **Revertido**: Primeiro você alegou na pergunta a seguinte declaração: `string sexo, pessoamaispesada;` , na edição você coloca  `string sexo = ""; var pessoamaispesada = "";` assim invalidando as respostas.

Comment: Na verdade @AugustoVasques a revertida pode até invalidar as respostas, mas, o problema era obscuro e não era por causa disso. O Problema era mais interno e na minha opinião deveria ter deixado o usuário colocar a totalidade do código que ai sim poderíamos apontar o problema real mediante uma resposta. A pergunta é ruim, é um faz para mim porque falta experiência no usuário e que eu acho que os usuários postam pergunta e acham que temos que adivinhar eu por exemplo espero eles colocarem o máximo de informação antes de responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo pelo fato das variáveis não possuírem inicialização (valor inicial definido). Basta atribuir um valor para elas conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
string sexo = "";
string pessoamaispesada = "";
```

A questão está um pouco confusa, mas pelo que interpretei seu programa rodando ficaria assim (uma das formas de fazer o método para calcular o mais pesado):

```
public static void VerificaMaisPesado()
{
    int pos = 2;
    string[] sexo = new string[pos];
    string[] nome = new string[pos];
    decimal[] peso = new decimal[pos];

    decimal pesoMax = 0;

    string pessoamaispesada = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Digite o nome da pessoa: ");
        nome[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Digite o sexo da pessoa {i} (M - masculino | F - feminino): ");
        sexo[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Digite o peso da pessoa: ");
        peso[i] = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < peso.Length; i++)
    {
        if (peso[i] > pesoMax)
        {
            pesoMax = peso[i];
            pessoamaispesada = nome[i];
        }
    }

    Console.Write("A pessoa mais pesada é {0}", pessoamaispesada);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

O erro é justamente esse que está escrito, você não inicializou a variável e tentou usar sem um valor nela, isso potencialmente daria erro, então compilar já impede. Então o que deve fazer? Dar um valor para a variável. Então isto resolveria:

```
var sexo = "";
var pesoMaisPesada = "";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Blanc.cs).

O segundo erro não deveria acontecer a não ser que o código esteja sendo apresentado de um jeito completamente fora do seu estado real.

Eu posso quase garantir que não vai resolver o problema total do código que parece fazer algo sem sentido aí. Deu só para responder essa parte.